# multi label misclassification rates

Tags: multi-class, confusion-matrix, multilabel

I'm looking for a way to efficiently describe the performance of a multi-label classification model (if possible, something like confusion matrix for the multi-class classification). I'm not sure if this question should be asked this way or on this forum.. but I just need some methods that can help in visualizing the misclassification rates ofeach class in a multi-label classification problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a multiclass confusion matrix.  It works exactly the same way a binary confusion matrix does, but with more entries.  I.E if you have three classes you will have a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Technically speaking, it can not be applied for multi label classification since multiple classes can belong simultaneously to one sample of data, however, for the multi class classification, only one class of n classes can belong to the sample.

Comment: Right, sorry I misunderstood/misread your post.  I was thinking you were asking for the multiclass confusion matrix.  If the number of labels you are applying is small enough, and/or the number of classes per label is small, you could try cross-classification.  For example if you were labeling both eye color and sex you could create a new variable that contains the information of both eye color and sex and create a confusion matrix with that new variable.  The classes for that new variable would look like brown_male, brown_female, blue_male, blue_female...etc.

Comment: I have 21 objects where most of them are present concurrently in the dataset. So it is a little bit tough to model it the way you proposed